Server responds differently to browser and fetch
I'm trying to fetch a download link from a server that has Cloudflare set up.
When I make a request with my browser it responds just fine (downloading the file), but when fetching with fetch() it responds with an HTML page.
I've already tried mimicking the request from the browser but it still responds with the HTML


fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 ...",
          Accept:
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml ...",
          ...
        },
      })



Inspecting the HTML I found an inline function that aparently loads the data from the desired website:


<script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '3',cZone: "...", cUPMDTk:"... .m3u8?"}()</script>



But my browser prevents this load of data:
Firefox error Message
Do you have any idea of what I can do to get the actual download from the link?

Look like it’s trying to load a file from disk

When you go to the URL in the browser, it opens a page with JavaScript that starts the download. fetch() doesn't run scripts in the returned code.

If you want to execute the code, extract it from the response text and call eval().

@Barmar How could I simulate that behavior so that I can download the file?

I just told you: extract the JavaScript (everything between <script> and </script> from the response text, then use it as the argument to eval()

You need to execute the JavaScript that the URL is returning.
async doDownload(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 ...",
      Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml ...",
      ...
    },
  });
  let text = await response.text();
  let match = text.match(/<script>(.*)<\/script>/);
  if (match) {
    eval(match[1]);
  }
}

doDownload(url);

